# Make pushViewController Transition Immediately upon Clicking Row

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I have seen apps that will push to the new `viewController` immediately upon clicking the table item, then display an `activityIndicator` while the new view is loading. I know how to add the activityIndicator to the `ProfileViewController`, but how do I make the table push to the new controller immediately upon clicking the item rather than waiting for the content to load?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{
  ProfileViewController *profileViewController = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];

  //profileViewController.title = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
  profileViewController.newsArticle = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:profileViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Any assistance or guidance would be wonderful. Thank you all!

Comment: Doesn't this code do what you want? Or, does the [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] line take time to execute?

Comment: @rdelmar, it seems to be the [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] line that is taking so long to load. If i remove it then the app crashes as it doesn't have anything to reference.

Comment: Can you post your Code from `ViewDidLoad` of `profileViewController` ? if you firing some request in `ViewDidLoad` then it will take some Time to Load instead fire that request in `ViewDidAppear`.

Comment: Sure @SibaPrasadHota, I actually load a ton of other content in the viewDidLoad of the profileViewController. For example, many database calls, getting images from the web, etc... do I need to put this in the viewDidAppear instead?

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota, you are awesome... you totally jogged my memory. That was way I needed to do, put everything in the viewDidAppear rather than the viewDidLoad... THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't to an operation on the new view controller until the viewDidAppear. And then you fire off something that is asynchronous and does not block the main thread:

1. viewDidLoad: setup activity indicator
2. viewWillAppear: start acrivity indicator
3. viewDidAppear: fire off async process
4. Delegate method/notification/block: when process is done update UI with data